# Selenium problema com get!

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

## O que desejo

Abrir um navegador utilizando Selenium, fazendo acessar um site (ex.: http://www.google.com.br) `driver.get("http://www.google.com");` e escrever no campo text dele uma busca `element.sendKeys("Cheese!");` apos finalizar submeter o formulário para efetuar a busca `element.submit();`

## Problema

A instancia do driver é feita com sucesso e o Firefox abre, porém fica na tela inicial "Pagina em Branco" sem fazer mais nada. Não possui mensagem de erro, apenas não faz.

## Código

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class TesteAutomatizado  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        element.submit();

        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

[Pagina do exemplo](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations)

## Pergunta

Busquei em vários lugares na internet e os exemplos são os mesmos. Alguém teria alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo?

Comment: Qual a versão do Firefox? Normalmente encontro problemas ao utilizar o Selenium nas versões mais novas do Firefox. Realize o teste com outro Driver ou dê downgrade na sua versão do Firefox para testar.

Comment: Pode ser mesmo, recentemente atualizei para a ultima versão.

Comment: Tenta fazer o teste em mais de um navegador, para verificar incompatibilidades Em alguns testes que fiz dá diferença entre Chrome e Firefox.

Comment: Nunca tentei com o Firefox cara, eu utilizo o drive do Chrome que eu acho mais simples... caso interesse tenho um tutorial para isso:
http://wp.me/p2DZEL-4P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuidado ao atualizar a versão do Firefox. Olhe antes o [*changelog*](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG) do Selenium e veja qual a última versão compatível.

Infelizmente, como o Firefox está mudando muito de versão, é complicado para o time do Selenium gerar uma versão somente para compatibilidade.

Olhando o log que mencionei e linkei, a última versão do Selenium (2.41.0), suporta o Firefox 28. Se não me engano, foi lançada a versão 29 em abril.

É uma dor de cabeça, mas eu sempre precisei instruir o pessoal da empresa a ficar com uma versão fixa do Firefox, desabilitando a atualização automática.

Uma alternativa é usar uma versão portável do Firefox em outro diretório e especificar o executável na inicialização do Selenium/WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

Fazer downgrade da versão do Firefox nem sempre é necessário.
Assim que o Firefox é atualizado uma nova versão da API do Selenium é lançada para ficar em conformidade com a ultima versão do browser.

Comment: Nem sempre. Mas só para citar um exemplo, até hoje não há uma versão do Selenium para o FF 29. Isso significa que qualquer pessoa que por alguma razão instalou a última versão do FF há mais de 20 dias atrás não consegue executar o Selenium com ela.